# Sorting files list after creation time, stopped working on network location

Tags: python, sorting

I have created a list of files using glob.
This list I sort after creation time.

The code has been working - but suddenly stopped.

It still works when files are in a local folder.
It also work on the network location when there are only a few files.

Typically there are +5000 files on the network location.

```
def get_files(folder):
    files_list = glob.glob(folder)
    files_list.sort(key=os.path.getctime)
    return files_list
```

It generates the files_list with no problem, but it stalls when it comes to the sorting.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't just the delay from stat'ing each file? Fetching metadata from network file systems is usually much slower than from local file systems.

Comment: You are right - Actually it returns the data after a long while.

Answer (score 0):

`getctime` on a remote file is a network operation. That means that under the hood, you have a (large) network access to get the list of files and then one network acces per file to get its timestamp.

According to the documentation for `scandir` it can save resources by getting the attributes of the file on the first folder access. So you should try:

```
def get_files(folder):
    entries = os.scandir(folder)
    files_list = [entry.name for entry in sorted(entries, key=lambda x:x.stat().c_time)]
```

Comment: Hi - Thank you for your proposal.

It gives this error though:
TypeError: sorted expected 1 argument, got 2

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's what you want.

```
def get_files(folder):
    files_list = glob.glob(folder)
    return sorted(files_list, key = os.path.getctime)
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposal.
My code would not pass on the sorted list - Thank you for letting me know.
It is a shorter and better code than mine - But unfortunately it takes the same time to process.